# How to get an array of values for the router "segment"?

Tags: zend-framework2

I use a form with a multiupload. My addAction save information regarding the downloaded files in the database, and obtains an array lastInsrtId() values. If the upload was successful, I need to be redirected to editAction, where a user can see a list of downloaded files and user can edit file attributes such as title, description and alt attribute for images for each downloaded file using this files list. How do I pass an array of values ​​in the route? Here is my code addAction:

```
// upload success
$fileIds = $this->getContentService()->makeFiles($parent, $data);
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('sc-admin/file/edit', array('ids' => $fileIds));
```

Here is the definition for a route that should display a list of files for editing:

```
'edit' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/edit[/:ids]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'sc-file',
            'action' => 'edit',                
        ),                
    ),                
),
```

But it generates an error for editAction

```
rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I do not want to use the session whenever the parameters necessary to pass an array of values, because it is a matter solely routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever seen this url?

```
http://foo.bar/baz?array(1=>2,3=>4)
```

Probably not. You got an error message so do as the error message says. This has **nothing** to do with Zend Framework, this is basic PHP (too many people often forget what's the core...).

```
array('ids' => serialize($data))
```

See [php:`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php) and [php:`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Serialization - it's not bad. But still would like the user can to dial the address manually. Furthermore, the method should take both single identifier and array. As far as I know, php not have a function isSerialize(). Does anyone have any ideas? In any case, thank you.

Comment: Look, you're done! What prevents serialization instead use "implode (',' $ data)" You super! Thank you again!